# Xamarin Android and Dependecy Injection

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, dependency-injection, xamarin.android

I develop an Android application with Xamarin. Suppose I have an Activity and it depends on some interface:

```
interface IFoo
{
    // methods
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    private readonly IBar _bar;

    public Foo(IBar bar)
    {
        _bar = bar;
    }

    // methods implementation
}
// dependency injection somewhere in Application class
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo>();   

public class MyActivity : Activity
{
    // it's incorrect constructor and this code will not be compiled
    public MyActivity(IFoo foo)
    {
        _foo = foo;
    }

    private readonly IFoo _foo;
}
```

I would like to inject instance of IFoo in MyActivity's constructor but as you know it is impossible to create constructor with parameters. How could I pass initialized instance of IFoo with all its dependencies to MyActivity? I use Unity as Dependency Injection framework (but I can change it).

Comment: Why would you like to inject instance of `IFoo` in `MyActivity`'s constructor ? If you want to initialize `UnityContainer`, you could do it in Android `Application` class.

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT and how couldI use it inside Activity class?

Comment: @Pupkin Did you resolve this issue? If so how did you do it?

Answer (score 0):

In you app class define:

```
public static UnityContainer container { get; private set; }

var container = new UnityContainer();
```

register your interface

```
container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo>();
```

and resolve as below

```
var myFoo = container.Resolve<IFoo>()
```

Note: Don't forget to add the namespace `using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;`